# Taking the difference of two Multilevel indexed Pivot table columns

Tags: python, pandas

Please see the data set below.

```
   data={'Claim Number':[200932768,102349182,200943556,200932768,300943556,400943556],'Reserve':[200000,50000,0,200000,5000,0],'Paid':[0,139000,0,0,139000,0],'Key':['Feb','Feb','Feb','March','March','March']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
table=df.pivot_table(index='Claim Number',columns='Key',values=['Reserve','Paid'],fill_value=0)
```

I'm trying to create two additional columns Change in Reserve, and Change in Paid.

Which would be the difference of the [Change in Reserve in March]-[Change in Reserve in Feb], as well as the same for "Paid".

What I have been doing is singling pit " Reserve" and Paid as follows.

```
table=df.pivot_table(index='Claim Number',columns='Key',values=['Reserve'],fill_value=0)

table.reset_index(inplace=True)
table["Change in Reserve"]=table['March']-table['Feb']
```

However, this method although provides what I want is inefficient, since I have to do the same calculation for 'Paid', and the  perform a join.
Would there be an easier method to perform the desired output?

Perhaps my approach in using a pivot table is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
df_g = df.groupby(['Claim Number', 'Key']).sum().reset_index()

diff_claim = df_g['Claim Number'] == df_g['Claim Number'].shift()
reserve_change = df_g['Reserve'] - df_g['Reserve'].shift()

ls = pd.Series([])
for index, value in reserve_change.iteritems():
    if diff_claim[index]:
       ls[index] = reserve_change[index]
    else:
       ls[index] = None

df_g['change'] = ls
```